# Could not connect statsd exporter to AirFlow

Tags: airflow, statsd

I'm trying to connect statsd exporter to airflow, but when I set `statsd_on = True` in airflow.cfg and try to restart airflow-webserver I get

```
ERROR - Could not configure StatsClient: No module named 'statsd', using DummyStatsLogger instead.
```

How can I load this module or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pip3 install statsd` returns `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsd (from versions: none)`

Answer (score 0):

Install statsd manualy from https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd. But since I could not find setup.py there, I installed from https://github.com/rnt/python-statsd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).